# Associated Classes Definition

Tags: java

Quick question(s)! According to my Java Computer Science textbook, "If a class C1 is associated with another class, C2, then C1 depends on C2 for its implementation..." is a true statement in the T/F section of a practice test. Is the 'associated' keyword 1-directional, as in this 'C1 is associated with C2' has a different meaning than 'C2 is associated with C1?' Also, when is this the case besides in the case of abstract classes and interfaces, and what would associated mean in these contexts?
Thanks

Comment: Association is one-directional i.e If c1 depends on C2, it doesn't mean C2 depends on C1. Also, association can include inheritance as well as composition and aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Association** is relation between two separate classes which establishes through their Objects. Association can be one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many.

**e.g Car and Driver**

Both can live independent of each other.

**Aggregation** is a special case of association.It contains **has-a** relationship.It is one-directional.

**e.g Wallet and Money classes.**

Wallet has money.

**Composition** is a restrictive case of aggregation. In this one object requires another object to exist.

**e.g Car and Engine**

Answer (score 0):

[in java relationships in class to class is two type 1) inheritance 2) association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTMdt.png)